# PHP empty action form Vs PHP self

Tags: php, html, forms

I have any form for submit using `PHP` self url. For action URL i have two way:

- insert empty like this : `<form action="">`
- insert `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`.

Which way is better and safe?

Comment: Generally, I use `action=""`, but this question seems primarily opinion based.

Comment: I would agree with @ʰᵈˑon this one. "" is a reliable action URL

Comment: php_self can be an injection hazard, since it's essentially what the script was invoked as. if it contains html, it'll show up verbatim in the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't count on non-standard behavior which is what happens when a browser submits a form to the same page when  no form action is specified. Always be clear and concise to avoid unforseen issues. Especially when all of it is within your control.

Comment: Fair answer, can you give an example when action="" may cause an error in action route ?

Comment: All of the browsers that I know of will submit the form to the same URL so in practice, this won't be an issue. *But*, in theory, there are other user-agents that crawl documents and they may not exhibit the same behavior. By explicitly declaring a URL you are removing this ambiguity (as well as making it clear that a missing action is not an error).

Comment: @JohnConde Wow, never thought of that! +1

Comment: Possible point of interest: `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` should possibly be considered user-input in this case, so you should sanitize it.

Answer (score 1):

A third option is probably best: the page that makes the form should know its own url, so enter that. @johnconde is correct in the argument to not rely on non-standard behaviour, but the alterative you give isn't much better: you hope the user didn't do something (or was tricked in doing something) unexpected.

random link: http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2013/05/20/php_self-and-cross-site-scripting that explains this.

Better to just know your page, and echo the actual page you are looking at.